Why loss value in probablistic-layers at the beginning of training process is large value
I try to build model with conv-flipout layer and desne-flipout layer instead of conv2d and dense-layer, but when training the model, at first the loss value become large as (100) then decrease slowly and the accuracy is good and increase.
Is it normal the loss value in flipout-layers (or any probabilistic-layer) becomes large?
Note: when I replace these layer with conv2d and dense-layer, the loss becomes low.
I will add the model:
    feature_extractor = pretraind-model like vgg16
    for layer in feature_extractor.layers:
        layer.trainable = False
    # Add residual blockt
    x = feature_extractor.output
    
    x = tfp.layers.Convolution2DFlipout(32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', name='conv2dflipout', 
kernal_divergence_fn=divergence_fn)(x)
    x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
    x = tfp.layers.Convolution2DFlipout(
                filters=64, kernel_size = (1,1),  kernel_divergence_fn=divergence_fn,
                bias_divergence_fn=divergence_fn,
                padding='same', activation= 'relu', name='conv2dflipout')(x)
    
    x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    x = tfp.layers.DenseFlipout(
                units=128,kernel_divergence_fn=divergence_fn,
                kernel_posterior_fn = tfpl.default_mean_field_normal_fn(is_singular=False),
                kernel_prior_fn = tfpl.default_multivariate_normal_fn,
                bias_prior_fn = tfpl.default_multivariate_normal_fn,
                bias_posterior_fn = tfpl.default_mean_field_normal_fn(is_singular=False),
                bias_divergence_fn = divergence_fn,
                activation=tf.nn.relu)(x)
    x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
    x = tfp.layers.DenseFlipout(
                units = 2,
                kernel_divergence_fn=divergence_fn,
                kernel_posterior_fn = tfpl.default_mean_field_normal_fn(is_singular=False),
                kernel_prior_fn = tfpl.default_multivariate_normal_fn,
                bias_prior_fn = tfpl.default_multivariate_normal_fn,
                bias_posterior_fn = tfpl.default_mean_field_normal_fn(is_singular=False),
                bias_divergence_fn = divergence_fn,
                activation=None)(x)
    
    x = tfpl.OneHotCategorical(3,convert_to_tensor_fn=tfp.distributions.Distribution.sample)(x)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=feature_extractor.input, outputs=x)

    divergence_fn = (lambda q, p, _: tfd.kl_divergence(q, p) /  # pylint: disable=g-long-lambda
                                tf.cast(NUM_TRAIN_EXAMPLES, dtype=tf.float32))


i figured i have data which have 11000 example  , and data have 5000 example , the loss when training data have larger data is less than the fewer examples, because of divergence_fn. but still the loss is bigger than standard deep learning model
